# microsoft rsa channel cryptographic provider not available during creating certificate Sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, cryptography, ssl-certificate

Sql Server: Sql Server Express 2014
OS: Window 10
IIS: 10.0

I am not able to get the option of **"microsoft rsa *channel* cryptographic provider"** during the creation of certification on Computer I am getting the option **"microsoft rsa *Schannel* cryptographic provider"**.

I want secure connection to sql server so I created the Certificate Using **"MMC.exe"**

1. Install the SQL Server certificate using Microsoft Management ConsoleCreate certificate.
2. Configuring SQL Server to accept encrypted connections

by fallow this steps [Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3299/how-to-configure-ssl-encryption-in-sql-server/)

After Step Two I Restart the Server And Got error

> The Request fails or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
>   Consult the event log or other application error log for details

then after looking log i got the issue

> Unable to load user-specified certificate [Cert Hash(sha1)
>   "AB61993A9D9C5AF442F47053E36F169EB6058E20"]. The server will not
>   accept a connection. You should verify that the certificate is
>   correctly installed. See "Configuring Certificate for Use by SSL" in
>   Books Online.

from more investigation i got this link which is link to my issue [support microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/928779)

**it is giving solution**

To work around this problem, use any of the following methods:

1. Do not specify any certificate. Therefore, SQL Server generates a
   self-signed certificate. To do this, leave the Certificate box blank
   in SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Use a certificate that uses the "**Microsoft RSA Channel Cryptographic
   Provider"** cryptographic service provider for the SQL Server
   certificate.

By running the certutil -v -store my. it show that **microsoft rsa schannel cryptographic**

Step one is working for me now step two i want to install the certificate i try to check the change the **microsoft rsa Schannel cryptographic**  to **microsoft rsa channel cryptographic** but during the Flow I am not able to see the microsoft rsa channel cryptographic provider.

Comment: Could it just be a spelling mistake? I can't find any references to "Microsoft RSA Channel Cryptographic Provider". See MSDN > Microsoft Cryptographic Service Providers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386983(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your link to "support microsoft" does not go to the specific article. Can you fix it please.

Comment: It is definitely a typo in the documentation. The right provider name is "Microsoft RSA **S**Channel Cryptographic Provider". However, I would suggest to use "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" CSP as it supports more secure and modern symmetric algorithms.

Comment: Thanks but read this document https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/928779 .  I am able to get the certificate. but issue i am facing When i map the Certificate to SQL Server for encrypted connection string.